# Does Jaggery support filter?

Tags: java, servlet-filters, wso2, jaggery-js

Can we add custom filter in JaggeryJS to do something like session check?

Is there any samples about writing custom filter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is, just map all urls into a single jag file.Then do all the checks and include the rest. There is no such specific way to do like servlet filter in JaggeryJS.

Comment: I want to use filter to check whether user login or not, and some other things like request parameter encoding.

Comment: Now how i check login user session is writing a separated jag file to do the checking, all the other jag files will include this file.